# How to pass additional arguments to a function when using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I would like to read several png images by utilizing the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `cv2.imread`.

Problem is that I don't know where to place `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` tag/argument to preserve alpha channel (transparency).

The following code works but alpha channel is lost. Where should I place the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` argument?

```
import cv2
import concurrent.futures
images=["pic1.png", "pic2.png", "pic3.png"]
images_list=[]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    images_list=list(executor.map(cv2.imread,images))
```

For example, the following return an error:
`SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error`

```
import cv2
import concurrent.futures
images=["pic1.png", "pic2.png", "pic3.png"]
images_list=[]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    images_list=list(executor.map(cv2.imread(images,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `lambda` that accepts one argument `img` and pass the argument to the `imread` function along with the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`.

```
import cv2
import concurrent.futures
images=["pic1.png", "pic2.png", "pic3.png"]
images_list=[]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    images_list=list(executor.map(lambda img: cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED),images))
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander

I confirm that this works! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using `functools.partial()` which you can consider to be a function with its parameters *"partially pre-filled"*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import glob
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# List of image names
imageNames=glob.glob("*.png")

# Define a partially complete function where some parameters are pre-filled
loader = partial(cv2.imread, flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

with ThreadPool() as pool:
    images = list(pool.map(loader, imageNames))
```

---

Note that, in general, especially with images which tend to take a lot of memory, it is a poor idea to load large numbers of images all at the same time into lists in order to process them because you create exceptional strain on the memory of your computer.

So, say you want to identify exceptionally dark or light images, or images with lots of red in them, it is better to run a bunch of threads that each load one image, process it and then move to the next image than to accumulate all images in memory before processing them.